# Why is nodejs converting my object key strings to object literal?

Tags: javascript, node.js, object

Take this code for example:

```
test = {};
test['hey'] = {
    a:'noob'
}
console.log(test);
```

It will output: 
[image]

Now, take this:

```
test = {};
test[1] = {
    a:'muffin'
}
console.log(test);
```

It will output: [image]

My question is: Is it possible to use a string as an object key? (It's possible already, but nodejs is converting it into object literal), which I don't want. I want it to be inside single quotes like:

```
{ 'hey': { a: 'test' }}
```

Comment: You mean you want the keys to be printed with quotes?

Comment: Yeah like how `1` is already, but with a string.

Comment: Nodejs is't converting anything, it's just the way it prints objects to console.

Comment: @NiCkNewman Why do you care how it prints out? What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Sounds like a XY problem to me. Whatever printed by `console.log` is just the representation of the object. What is the actual problem?

Comment: Sorry guys, just got worried about the single quote thing... not sure why since it behaves the same. Learned something new I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Object keys are always strings. There is no difference between the two different ways of writing the objects.

The object:

```
{ 'hey': { a: 'test' }}
```

is exactly the same as:

```
{ hey: { a: 'test' }}
```

The code for showing the object as text simply has logic for writing the shorter form. If it hadn't, you would see all identifiers quoted:

```
{ 'hey': { 'a': 'test' }}
```

You only need to use quotes around the name if you are using any characters that can't be used in an identifier. Example:

```
{ '{ an : "unusual name" }': { a: 'test' }}
```

Comment: I see, so it's just the output in console is what confused me a bit, thank you. (Not node's fault, mine)